# How can I transform my iOS/Swift project to a state where I will be able to use live views?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have been working on my first iOS/Swift application for the past month or so, and have created all of my class declaration files (i.e. my .Swift files) in my main project folder. I would really like to use live views in my app, because as of right now I cannot build/run the app at all due to errors I don't know how to fix (I'll be posting about those later today in hope of finding someone who can help me fix them).

What would be the best way to go about converting all of my views into embedded frameworks so that I could use the Live Views feature of Xcode ? I am running Xcode 7 and wrote my app in Swift 2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently don't need to use frameworks for that anymore. At least it works just fine in Xcode 7 for me - for classes that are part of the main project.  Just mark your class as @IBDesignable.

But in order to show the preview, your code needs to be able compile, so you will need to resolve your issues first.

Comment: Great. I do have Xcode 7 beta 2, but I didn't know that we could just use live views with classes in our main project. Thanks for the info